# Removal of any arc from the graph does not change the length of the path!

Tags: graph-theory

how can I show the existence of 2 arc-disjoint shortest $s − t$ paths in $G$.

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a digraph, and let $\mathbb{l}: E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$ be a non-negative length function on the arcs. We are given two nodes $s$ and $t$ such that $t$ is reachable from $s$ in $G$, and the removal of any arc from $G$ does not change the length of the shortest s − t path. Prove that there are 2 arc-disjoint shortest $s − t$ paths in $G$.

Comment: is something unclear about the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that every two shortest paths have a common edge, we shall prove that an edge exists that is contained in every shortest path.

Construct a graph subgraph $G'$ of $G$. There is going to be an edge going from $u$ to $v$ if and only if there is a shortest $s-t$ path using that edge, notice that clearly we cannot have both an edge from $u$ to $v$ and one from $v$ to $u$ in $G'$, so we shall make $G'$ undirected.

If we can prove that $G'$ has a cut-edge then we would be done, because that edge (or the directed version of the edge, with the correct direction) is exactly the one we have to remove from $G$. Clearly any two $s-t$ paths in $G'$ have a common edge, so by Menger's theorem there is a cut edge.

Comment: In essence, construct an auxiliary undirected graph and apply Menger to it. Or the "base case" of menger, when all paths are edge disjoint. Allthough, this "base case" has similar difficulty to the other steps of the proof in Menger's theorem.

Comment: I still have a doubt on the existence of 2 arc-disjoint shortest s−t paths in G.

Comment: @DanBrumleve I think that you should start by convincing yourself that Menger's theorem is true.